Treeshaking is not there for chart.js npm
I'm using chart.js in my react-app but when I installed this package, I saw it has a single javascript bundle in the node_modules folder. When I used it in my app and bundled it using webpack, again it took a single big javascript chunk. Below is the analyzer for the same:
Image of Bundle-Analyzer for chart.js
It's taking approx. ~73 kb (gzipped). When I checked its rollup config, preserveModules: true was not there.
So I wanted chart.js to use preserveModules: true so that I'll have multiple smaller chunks (for Line, Bar, etc.) and I don't have to load a 73kb file in the client.
I was thinking of publishing the chart.js (with preserveModules: true) in our internal npm domain. But not sure how can we do this with just our app using webpack/rollup bundle.
Also, why are chart.js authors not tree-shaking this library or am I missing something?
I tried updating the rollup config for chart.js with preserveModules: true and on building, it's giving individual smaller javascript chunks for all the dir & files (based on src of chart.js). That would solve if they (the author of chart.js) add this feature so that I can just update all imports of chart.js to the actual path e.g. import LineController from 'chart.js/controller/controller.line'.
The expectation is to either have this functionality in chart.js (or maybe with using webpack) or any other way around not to load the entire big chart.js (of ~73 kb). I'm just using the Line & Bar chart.
